# Does gRPC+MPI require RDMA?

Tags: tensorflow, mpi, grpc, infiniband, rdma

Tensorflow allows for the options "gRPC", "gRPC+verbs" and "gRPC+mpi" when specifying a communication protocol. In the gRPC+verbs [documentation](https://github.com/baidu-research/tensorflow-allreduce/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/verbs), it clearly states that this protocol is based on RDMA. Meanwhile, in the gRPC+MPI [documentation](https://github.com/baidu-research/tensorflow-allreduce/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/mpi), it doesn't imply this at all, and initially I assumed that gRPC+mpi can run on any underlying network. However, [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8638151) research paper implies that gRPC+mpi is required to run over RDMA (see the end of page 3). Am I misinterpreting the research paper? Can gRPC+MPI in fact run over any network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, page 4 of the same research paper indicates that the MPI channel is simply capable of supporting RDMA.